# MobileFirst Platform Foundation Server, Consumer Edition

Tags: mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

I am trying to download MobileFirst Platform Foundation Server, Consumer Edition (MFPF_6.3_CE_INST_MGR_REP_MF_SVREN.zip). Can you please let me know where can I download this package from?

Answer (score 1):

The consumer/enterprise edition of MobileFirst Platform is available to you only if you have purchased a license.

Until then you can download the Developer Edition from http://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform

Note that from a Studio (Eclipse) perspective there is no difference between the Developer Edition to the Consumer and Enterprise Editions. The Studio is the same Studio.

What you get in addition are server artifacts allowing you to run on dedicated application server as you move from development to production, and the ability to use features such as Application Authenticity Protection.

Of course, you are also bound legally to buy MobileFirst Platform of you intend to go to production. [Contact IBM for that](http://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help). Once you do that you will also get instructions how to download the additional artifacts.

Comment: Thanks Idan. By default in the developers edition the server component are installed in the same box. Can I replicate the production scenario by configuring the server in different box in Developers edition?  Any steps?

Comment: No. The idea of the developer edition is that it's all-in-one.

Comment: any documentation on configuring IBM Mobilefirst server on a unix box

Comment: See here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/topics/c_install_config.html

Comment: We need to install mobilefirst server in a standalone server for Development purpose. Do we need to purchase license for Development instance also?

Comment: No... Just go to Eclipse and open the marketplace from help menu and search for "mobilefirst platform"